# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de número en JQuery y PHP'?

Tags: php, jquery

No sé cómo hacer una cosa muy fácil y a ver si alguien me dice cómo.
Tengo unas variables numéricas con decimales en PHP y quiero usarlas en un text() de JQuery. El caso es que no hay ningún problema y todo funciona bien, este es el código:

```
    <div class='area_texto'>
        <div class='juguete_descripcion'>
            <p>".$juguete['descripcion']."</p>
            <p><div id='recuadro_precio' class='precio'>";
                if($precio_rebaja[0] > $precio_producto[0]){
                    echo "
                    <span id='recuadro_precio_menor' class='precio'>".number_format($precio_producto[0]/100,2,'\'','.').$moneda."</span>
                    <span id='recuadro_rebaja_menor'>".number_format($precio_rebaja[0]/100,2,'\'','.').$moneda."</span>
                    <span id='recuadro_porcentaje_menor' >-".$porcentaje_descuento_menor."%</span>
                    <span id='recuadro_separar' > / </span>
                    <span id='recuadro_precio_mayor' class='precio'>".number_format(end($precio_producto)/100,2,'\'','.').$moneda."</span>
                    <span id='recuadro_rebaja_mayor'>".number_format(end($precio_rebaja)/100,2,'\'','.').$moneda."</span>
                    <span id='recuadro_porcentaje_mayor'>-".$porcentaje_descuento_mayor."%</span>";
                    
                }else{
                echo "
                <span id='recuadro_precio' class='precio'>".number_format($precio_producto[0]/100,2,'\'','.').$moneda."</span>
                <span class='juguetes_precio'>".number_format($precio_producto[0]/100,2,"'",'').$moneda." - ".number_format(end($precio_producto)/100,2,"'","").$moneda."</span>";
                }
    echo "</div></p>";

   if(busca_precio != '".$juguete['precio']."'){
                $('#precio_carrito').val(precio_mostrar); <!--Muestra precio actual del juguete-->
                $('#recuadro_precio_menor').text(precio_mostrar_decimales+'".$moneda."'); <!--Muestra precio del modelo seleccionado-->
                $('#recuadro_rebaja_mayor').text(precio_rebaja_mostrar_decimales+'".$moneda."'); <!--Muestra precio más alto-->
                $('#recuadro_porcentaje_mayor').text(porcentaje+'%'); <!--Muestra porcentaje de descuento-->
            }else{
                $('#recuadro_precio_menor').text('".($precio_producto[0]/100).$moneda."'); 
                $('#recuadro_precio_mayor').text('".(end($precio_producto)/100).$moneda."');
                $('#recuadro_rebaja_menor').text('".($precio_rebaja[0]/100).$moneda."');
                $('#recuadro_rebaja_mayor').text('".(end($precio_rebaja)/100).$moneda."');
                $('#recuadro_porcentaje_menor').text('".$porcentaje_descuento_menor."%');
                $('#recuadro_porcentaje_mayor').text('".$porcentaje_descuento_mayor."%');
                $('#recuadro_separar').text('/');
                $('#precio_carrito').val('".$juguete['precio']."');
            }
```

El problema viene cuando quiero cambiar el formato del número por pantalla. Sale un número estilo 9.99 pero me gustaría que saliese con coma arriba 9'99. Si hago un number_format deja de funcionar y no sale nada por pantalla y si hago un cast a string tampoco.
Tengo conocimientos medios de JQuery por lo que imagino que la solución es fácil pero no la encuentro.
¿Alguien me ayuda?
¡Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas. Quiero decir que con ideas que he sacado de vosotros lo he conseguido hacer, al final sin usar Ajax. He creado unos input='hidden' a los que he dado un value con la variable PHP, y las he recuperado con JQuery con .val() y así he podido hacer lo que quería al principio ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Eso ya no es un un numero, el formato 9'99 serian algo como coordenadas y no le veo soporte nativo a la conversión en ninguno de los dos lenguajes, asique te toca hacer un cambio de carácter o remplazando el punto, tienes dos formas de hacer por php:

*en php:*

```
echo $str = str_replace(".", "'", "9.99");
```

Link Ejemplo: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b3H5

Link Documentación `str_replace`: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

*en javascript:*

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(".", "'");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Haga clic en el botón para reemplazar "." con "'" en el párrafo siguiente:</p>

<p id="demo">Numero 9.99</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Ejemplo y Documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: No me funciona @Francisco Núñez... en cuanto meto algo distinto en el text() deja de funcionar y no lee lo que hay metido... solo me está funcionando con el código exacto que he puesto en la pregunta, es decir, con punto y no con coma

Comment: que es lo que no te funciona???

Comment: En cada #recuadro debe aparecer un valor distinto (un precio, por eso hay decimales). El text() lee y muestra en los recuadros las variables PHP pero solo si están en el formato estándar del tipo 9.99 y me gustaría poder ponerlo como 9'99, pero cuando están en este formato no aparece nada

Comment: entonces hacen falta datos en tu pregunta: el html donde se pegan los datos; tambien entiendes el concepto de que php se ejecuta del lado del servidor y el javascript de lado del cliente???

Comment: otra cosa la respuesta que te acabo de dar cambia el formato ya probaste o intentaste implementarlo, si no te funciona que error te sale??

Comment: Acabo de ponerl el HTML como me has dicho. Como está, funciona perfectamente, al seleccionar un precio aparece en #precio_carrito (y sus span correspondientes también aparecen sus precios correspondientes), pero si toco algo de los text() ya no aparece nada, y lo que necesito es poder cambiar el formato de lo que hay en los text()

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119854/discussion-between-francisco-nunez-and-kaixo-guti).

Answer (score 1):

me colgaré de la respuesta correcta de Francisco, por que no has entendido algo...

Tal y como el menciona, puedes usar `str_replace` para darle formato al numero. `number_format` en este caso NO debería funcionar, porque lo que quieres es un formato *string*, no numérico, por lo que arruinaría a perder el valor real.

Y dejemos claro, eso... NÚMERO.

*9'99* solo es un modo de presentación, por lo que para mostrarlo, le darás ese formato al número deseado. En cuanto a trabajarlo, siempre lo trabajaras como número.

Acá te dejo mi ejemplo, usando ingresos de `string` y `float`

```
string(4) "9.99"  //Ingreso string
float(9.99)       //Ingreso float
string(4) "9'99"  //Resultado del string
string(4) "9,99"  //Resultado del float
```

---

```
$n1 = "9.99";
$n2 = 9.99;
$n3 = str_replace(".", "'", $n1);
$n4 = number_format($n2, 2, ',', '.');
```

Ahora, si es que quieres trabajar números y darles formato correcto, seguirás trabajándolos como números, pero al final los mostraras como cadena con formato:

```
$n1 = 9.99;
$n2 = (string) $n1;
$n3 = str_replace(".", "'", $n1);
var_dump($n3); 
//Salida -> string(4) "9'99"
```